# Add item to map inside of struct in Golang

Tags: go

I have such struct defined.

```
type Pages struct {
  Items []map[string]string
}
```

In a for loop I am creating items with `var item = make(map[string]string)`.

Complete code

```
pages := Pages{}
for _, partitionKey := range keys {
    fields, err := redis.Strings(conn.Do("hgetall", partitionKey))
    if err == nil {
        var item = make(map[string]string)
        item["id"] = strings.Replace(partitionKey, "pages:", "", -1)
        for i := 0; i < len(fields); i += 2 {
            key, _ := redis.String(fields[i], nil)
            value, _ := redis.String(fields[i+1], nil)
            item[key] = value
        }
        fmt.Println("\n", item)
        // this does not work
        //append(pages.Items, item)
    }
}

fmt.Println(pages)
```

How do I add newly created item to Items array in Pages struct?

**Solution based on answers below.**

```
type Pages struct {
    Items []map[string]string `json:"items"`
}

pages := Pages{}
for _, partitionKey := range keys {
    item, err := redis.StringMap(conn.Do("hgetall", partitionKey))
    if err == nil {
        item["id"] = strings.Replace(partitionKey, "pages:", "", -1)
        pages.Items = append(pages.Items, item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the code can be replaced with a call to [redis.StringMap](https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#StringMap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pages.Items = append(pages.Items, item)
```